# changing values in DB not reflecting in solr

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a solr search already implemented. It showing values in the UI. Working fine. The problem here is, if i change any data in the DB, it is not reflecting in the UI. It is showing the old values. What should i do?

Comment: You should re-import data again into solr.

Answer (score 1):

Every time when you change something in DB you need to re-import data

http://localhost:8983/solr/your_core_name/dataimport?command=full-import

Make sure that handlder method is defined in solrconfig.xml

To reload a core (just in case)
I suppose you're using dataImportHandler 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

You can do it via GET method.

To reload a core: http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=your_core_name

Comment: After updating the db, if i run the above query with my core name, it is not updating the UI. Below is the reponse when i hit the url
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1590</int>
</lst>
</response>

Comment: That's fine.It means a core has been updated then you need to re-import data again  http://localhost:8983/solr//your_core_name/dataimport?command=full-import

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by "Oyeme" in above answer you should update the your core document  once data is updated in db.

if your using solrj client then you can add or update document in core .

[link to solrj documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ)

You need to update your document through code once you updated your document when it get updated in db , do commit your changes to solr core .

for committing your changes use SolrServer.commit() method this will commit your changes to core and will appear in search.